# Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, select-by-attribute, mac

I've got a layer in **QGIS** that is comprised of points. Its attribute table doesn't have (show) the corresponding **x** and **y** coordinates for each point. Is there a way for me to extract a list of coordinates for those points? (ideally into a **CSV**, but not required)

Also, for the exported list of coordinates (say, in a **CSV** file), how do I include the existing attribute table with it?

For your information, I am running QGIS on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis

Comment: You might be interested in my answer in another thread
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-gis-support-dxf-and-or-dwg

Comment: You could also use the MMQGIS plugin to export the geometry with the rest of the layer attributes to CSV file.

Comment: Qgis has gdal, so you can use, from a command window, ogrinfo to do this, like
'ogrinfo -sql -dialect sqlite "select id,st_astext(geometry) from myshapefile" myshapefile.shp', where the single quotes should not be used but delimit the command. Other types of featureclass can be used, but need appropriate mods to the select, a connection string when using a db, etc. Nice is the ability to use sql on non-sql sources like shapefiles.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Depending on your version, you should be able to right-click on the layer you want to export, and select **Save As...** Choose **Comma Separated Value** from the dropdown list of the dialog box that appears. Then, in the **Layers** part of the **OGR creation options**, type **GEOMETRY=AS_XY** or **GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ** depending on the dimensionality of your source data.

[image: QGIS Save vector layer as... dialog]

Comment: That's great and it works! One more thing: Can I also export columns I already have in the original layer's into the CSV, along with the X, Y coordinated? Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it works! Make sure you have the "Skip attribute creation" checkbox unchecked. I'm not a fan of negative checkboxes like that, it always makes me think twice about what state I need it in.

Comment: Very useful tips!

Comment: For anyone else on Windows 10 (QGIS 4.3.1) confused about where this gets saved, check your "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin" folder.

Comment: Note that if your geometry has somehow become a multipart geometry, `GEOMETRY=AS_XY` will [silently fail](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43196#issuecomment-840647958). You can can fix this by processing the layer with 'Multipart to singleparts'

Comment: This only works for `point` features. It doesn't work for `polygons` or `line` features.

Answer (score 31):

In the **Field calculator** in the **Attribute Table** you may use `$x` and `$y` to calculate your coordinates into a new attribute.

For that, open the **Attribute Table**, click on the **Field calculator** (top arrow) and enter `$x` or/and `$y` (middle arrow) in the expression pane. A preview of your newly created output is shown below (bottom arrow).

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get the X Y in different coordinate system? I mean the XY of my points is in WGS 84 but I would like to list the XY values in different coordinate system in my attribute table.

Comment: this works, but note that you have a wrong column label in this example...$x is longitude and $y is latitude.

Answer (score 9):

You may like this for the added detail which is gathered

For QGIS 1.7 on Win7
I open the attribute table for the layer, use the buttons to;
invert selection to select all rows, 
copy to clipboard

and paste into Excel. The first column contains Well Known Text information which maybe more useful to you.

**Edit**

I now use the plugin mmqgis to export geometry to csv, it is more desired by CAD users at the other end...

Comment: BWill, should we merge your other account @Willy?  That would help your reputation and simplify your interactions here.

Comment: Restored original edit.

Comment: When copying from the attribute table and pasting into Excel, sometimes a feature will occupy multiple rows, and this results in overwriting any data in the row below.

Answer (score 4):

Virtual layers enables you to do exactly that. It is an icon on the Layers Toolbar or you can go `Layer`->`Add layer`->Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`
Then you will face a window like the one below:

[image]

In the *Query* you can select geometry properties like *x* and *y* cooridnates and attributes values from the Attribute Table, like the *id* in the example.

Once you have a table with the desired fields, you can use `save as`and select csv as a format.

[image]

The underlying engine uses SQLite and Spatialite to operate, so the documentation for the queries could be found here: 
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=misc-docs

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago as [Calculating latitude and longitude of points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199). It's only true for QGIS 1.7 though (which I'm running on OSX and it seems quite stable).

Answer (score 3):

For your question if you have postgressql and built-in postgis you can do this adding new column which is named `coord_x` and `coord_y`. And sql to update this column is:

```
UPDATE table_name
      SET coord_x = X(the_geom),coord_y = Y(the_geom);
```

That is it.

Comment: Do you think you can help me with this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/268888/36393?

Answer (score 0):

**How to add coordinates to attribute table**
I was looking for an answer to the first part of the question as I just wanted to see the coordinates in QGIS. The information above helped me work out a solution so I am posting for other QGIS beginners. I am using Windows10 and QGIS 3.4

1. Open Layer Properties
2. Select Source Fields (initially only id existed)
   [image]
3. Select Field Calculator
4. Select Create new field, enter name and choose decimal number as Output field type
5. Choose Geometry on lower right list

[image]
6. Select $x for x coodinate and save
[image]
7. Repeat by selecting $y for y coordinate and your coordinates will appear in the attribute table.