# Export list of coordinates in a points layer to spreadsheet?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, point, features

This is similar to my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer), but I would like to ask it for ArcGIS, instead of QGIS. If I am supposed to somehow merge the questions, please let me know.

With an existing point feature class as a layer in an ArcMap 10 document, how do I obtain a list of the points' x y coordinates (ideally in a csv file)? The attribute table for this layer does not have that data.

What I would like is to export those points to a spreadsheet, with the existing attribute table, but also with columns representing each point's corresponding x, y coordinates. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to do this programmatically and with as little fuss as possible...

At least at 9.3, ArcMap has an 'Add XY Coordinates' tool (under the Data Management -> Features toolbox). You can run this, which will add a field for the X & Y components of the point coordinate.

You can open the attribute table of the layer and export (using the Options/Export menu on the attribute table) to a dbf, which you can then open in excel and save as a CSV file or whatever.

Comment: If you want to automate the process, simply add these tools and input/output files into a ModelBuilder tool.  Use the "Copy Rows" function to export just the table and not the shapefile.  CopyRows only saves to DBF, but the same process @Wolf mentioned above will work.  If you really want to get creative, export the model to a python script and then you could script the DBF->CSV conversion using pure python.