# Creating CSV with geometry as WKT in QGIS (with choosing field delimiter)

Tags: qgis, export, csv, well-known-text

Is there a way to choose the field delimiter when exporting a CSV with geometry as wkt in QGIS?

I have a shapefile with donut holes and I'd like to export it as a CSV. It's for a partner whose DB doesn't support spatial data.

I followed [Greg Krakow's methodology](http://georgiawildlife.com/node/2849) to add a WKT field to my exported file (when exporting to csv, add `GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` in the "Layer" field, but the exported field delimiter is a comma:
[image: CSV with WKT field]

The problem is that each coordinate pairs of my polygons (and I suspect it will be the same for lines) are separated by a comma too so I can't import the data back into QGIS

With point shapefile, it works like a charm.

Does anyone know if I can choose my field delimited when exporting to CSV? Choose a semicolon for instance?

I search on the web and QGIS's documentation but didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you checked the help page yet: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html. It describes how to change the separator.

Comment: I was looking for QGIS specifically... didn't think of looking for GDAL's help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to export to CSV, using other than a comma, by separating the layer creation options in the Save As.. dialog with linebreaks.

Neither comma, nor space-separating them (even when they were in quotes) worked, but the linebreaks did the trick. To emphasize..

***THIS APPROACH WORKED*** (linebreak-separated):

```
GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON
LINEFORMAT=CRLF
```

***But these approaches did NOT work...***

(space-separated options):

`GEOMETRY=AS_WKT SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON`

(comma-separated options):

`GEOMETRY=AS_WKT, SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON`

(quoted, and either space or comma-separated LCOs):

`"GEOMETRY=AS_WKT", "SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON"`

As @underdark noted, [there are some additional options discussed on the OGR CSV driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) you may want to be aware of. Specifically, the `SEPARATOR` parameter will accept either `SEMICOLON` or `TAB` in addition to `COMMA`. Also, you may want to experiment with the `LINEFORMAT` parameter, which supports either `CRLF` (dos/windows) or `LF` (unix).

A picture says a thousand words, so here's a screen grab. :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I don't know why though, but when I try to import my csv into QGIS, it says that it's not a valid layer and it can be added to the map...? I tried with a simple polygon (linestring and polygon) and it didn't work neither :( So I guess it's another question now... ;)

Comment: ...interesting. I'm not sure how to explain that. I tried adding the one I created to the map and it worked. Then I tried adding a new one, as it created it (i.e. via the "Add saved file to map" option), and it also worked. What version of QGIS? 1.8?

Comment: 1.8.0-Lisboa. It's working when I use the "Add saved file to map", not when I use the "Add delimited text layer" button. The semicolon delimiter is check as well as my field "WKT" selected for the geometry... It worked with a point layer earlier though...

Comment: Ahh.. try going through the "Add Vector Layer.." button (like you would to add a shapefile), then browse into the folder with your `.csv`. At the bottom of the "Open OGR Supported Vector Layer" dialog, set "Files of type:" to `Comma Separated Value [OGR]`. Then your `.csv` should appear, and I bet it'll work.

Comment: You bet right! It worked with the "Add delimited text layer" after I opened my csv in Excel and resaved it too... Strange, but if it's working with the "Add Vector Layer" button, I'm ok with that. Strange behavior though...

Answer (score 5):

Settings for QGIS 3 using "Layer Options":

[image]