# Writing vector layer to CSV file with geometry using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, geometry, csv

I use Python try to write vector layer file to csv file with this code:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mylayer, r'c:\temp\xyz.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV")
```

It can export to xyz.csv but only attributes show in the csv, not the geometry column.

How can I export both attribute and spatial data into csv file?

Comment: Here is the same question and the solution [link][1].

  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43129/create-a-csv-with-geometry-as-wkt-in-qgis-and-choosing-the-field-delimiter

Comment: I'm sorry for make question not clear.

my work use python with pyqgis write vector layer to csv file.
I want csv file have geometry but it not.
still need answer

Comment: Depends on what type of vector layer you want to export. For point layer you could just add the lat, long values as attribute table columns. For all others you need WKT

Comment: Thank you Curlew, I work with point and polygon layer.
for point layer you mean add lat, lon column in attribute table?
how about polygon?

Comment: if anyone mark duplicate question, 
please show link to right answer for me.
thanks

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? This question here is aimed particularly at python, which is not covered by the linked answer.

Comment: Thank you Matthias Kuhn, you are right.
I can't contact people who mark duplicate my question and and StackExchange.com comment to ask a new question so I make a new question here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63136/can-pyqgis-write-shape-file-to-csv-with-geometry-data-using-python

Comment: You don't need to open a new question just because someone suggested this could be a duplicate. It's fine as it is.

Answer (score 10):

A similar answer was provided from this post:

[Save as .csv with coordinates in both QGIS 2.2 and PyqGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/save-as-csv-with-coordinates-in-both-qgis-2-2-and-pyqgis?lq=1)

Just add `layerOptions ='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ` at the end:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/shapefile", "name", "ogr")
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, r'c:\temp\xyz.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing a problem in this, If I type this in console it does not save the Spatial data but only the attributes. But if I save it manually it works. I am using QGIS 2.14.12.

Comment: @SunnyNaik - The `layerOptions` parameter now requires a list of string values whereas before a single value was enough (as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220219/error-when-writing-shape-to-wkt-with-pyqgis-and-qgis-2-14)). So your last line would look like: `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, r'c:\temp\xyz.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])`