# Converting shape length/area data to latitude/longitude

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tableau

I am attempting to import publicly available shapefile data from http://gis.utah.gov/data/boundaries/zip-codes/ into Tableau for a data visualization project.

Unfortunately, the .shp file and .gdb database that are available for download include only the shape length / area for each of the Utah zip codes.

My goal is to convert these from the current NAD 1983 UTM 12N (EPSG: 26912) format into latitude / longitude coordinates that can be read into Tableau.

I am using QGIS 2.0.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layer is provided as a polygon so you'll need to convert the polygons to points and calculate the XYs of each point.

- Enable 'on the fly' CRS projections in Project Properties
- Ensure that the Selected CRS is the CRS you want to project the data to
- Add vector layer
- Right click layer and "Save vector layer as..."
- Select the CRS you want the layer exported to
- Save layer and re-add the layer to the project
- Convert the polygon to points using Vector-->Geometry Tools-->Extract nodes
- Ensure the points layer is added to the project
- Open Attributes table for point layer
- Toggle editing mode on
- Open field calculator
- Add two new calculated fields using the $x and $y funcitons under Geometry for each respective field
- Save edits and toggle off edit mode

This should give you a point file with the vertices for each polygon and the respective calcualted X and Y values for each point in the chosen CRS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware which format is needed for importing into Tableau. One human-readable standard format is Well-known Text (WKT). It's just a list of coordinates with defined syntax and can be converted into any format you need with some simple scripting.

On reprojecting to geographic coordinates: [Reprojecting vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/how-to-reproject-a-vector-layer-in-qgis)

On exporting a text file with vertex coordinates in WKT: [Create a csv with geometry as WKT in QGIS (and choosing the field delimiter)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43129/create-a-csv-with-geometry-as-wkt-in-qgis-and-choosing-the-field-delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

I created some videos that take you through the entire process of taking a shape file, bringing it into QGIS, exporting the geometry data, converting it into Tableau format, and then loading it into Tableau.

http://www.excelacom.com/resources/blog/tableau-geospatial-reporting-made-easy