# export shp positions to csv pyqgis

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, point, csv

I'm trying to export positions of a set of points using pyqgis

I saw the numerous posts concerning exporting shp dataset to csv but the command used in all of them is not working.

- [How to write vector layer to csv file with geometry by PYTHON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61857/how-to-write-vector-layer-to-csv-file-with-geometry-by-python)
- [Create a csv with geometry as WKT in QGIS (and choosing the field delimiter)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43129/create-a-csv-with-geometry-as-wkt-in-qgis-and-choosing-the-field-delimiter)
- [Save as .csv with coordinates in both QGIS 2.2 and PyqGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93123/save-as-csv-with-coordinates-in-both-qgis-2-2-and-pyqgis?lq=1)

My code line is:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(final_palmtrees_layer, result_path+'_trees_pos.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions ='GEOMETRY=AS_XY')
```

There are two issues with this line

- I wrote it in the console and i'm getting a "7" error code in the console, but I cannot find what it means.
- I put it in a script and i'm getting the csv file but only the attributes, not the points position + excel tells that the file is corrupted

Comment: Which QGIS version and platform are you using?

Comment: QGIS 2.18.14 on windows 10

Comment: Try using `layerOptions` as a list. E.g. `layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XY']`

Comment: I now get error code 3 with `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, 'C:\...\xy.csv', "utf-8", None, "CSV", layerOptions =['GEOMETRY=AS_XY'])`. Indeed it's written list in QGIS API, I just saw it. Is there a place to see error codes ?

Comment: [https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3a4405a59d8f8ac147878cae5bd9bade](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a3a4405a59d8f8ac147878cae5bd9bade). Also, be careful with backward slashes. Use `r'C:\...\xy.csv'` or `'C:\...\\xy.csv'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue by:

- adding 'r' in front of the path: `r'C:\...\xy.csv'`
- use a list and not a string as `layerOptions` parameter

Thanks Joseph