# Extract Polygon Coordinates from Shapefile data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, qgis-2, geolocation

I have some building data (polygons) as a shapefile in QGIS 2.18. I'm trying to add a location coordinates (the polygons rough center) and an array of the polygons coordinates (its points). I've been able to do the first one using vector --> analysis tools --> mean coordinates which generates a new layer. I can't work out how to get the polygons coordinates though? The end goal is to extract this all to a spreadsheet if that makes a difference.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @qu1ckdry! Are you wanting the coordinates of the polygon vertices?

Comment: If your end goal is to extract it to a spreadsheet, you can _right-click_ your layer, select `Save As...`, change the `Format` to csv and change the `GEOMETRY` to `AS_WKT`. This will create a csv file with a field containing the coordinates of all vertices for each polygon feature :)

Comment: Yes this does what I need! Thanks! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! I suggest accepting @artwork21's answer as he describes the steps to bring the csv back into QGIS. Also, I think a _very_ similar question was already asked here: [How to export Polygons to CSV with coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/how-to-export-polygons-to-csv-with-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a common id in the centroid layer and vertice table using Joseph's comment/method you could bring both layer and table in QGIS and perform a join on the common id field and export that joined layer to a .csv.

Comment: Thanks for your response artwork21. There is a common ID but I've decided to join everything together in excel as it's easier for me to work with!