# Exporting data from a WFS service to csv file using qgis

Tags: qgis, csv

I have a service that contains a list of points with some meta data and I would like to export this to a csv file. I remember doing this some months ago and it worked well, but now I can't find the method (or plugin?) that I used.

Has anyone done something similar and know how to export data from a WFS service to a CSV file using QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be same as here: [Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer)

> select "Save As...", choose "Comma Separated Value", and in the "Layers" part of the "OGR creation options", type "GEOMETRY=AS_XY" or "GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ"