# How to find polygons centroids?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, centroids, ftools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get list of coordinates for points in a layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer)

Sorry for another basic question - my map is almost done but now my boss wants me to enter new outbreaks (that we don't have coordinates for) into a map that has animal population data for several provinces (one shapefile for each country).

At this point all I have for these newer outbreaks is the province that the outbreak was in - my boss has said that I can input the coordinates (roughly) for each outbreak by finding the centroid. I've used ftools for this, I've been importing data for outbreaks from excel files (using a delimited text layer) - for the outbreaks without coordinates (for which I only have data telling me what province the outbreak was in) I presume I'm going to have to make an Excel/DBF file with these coordinates. My boss says that I can get these coordinates by finding the centroids.

I've tried using "Polygon Centroids" via the ftools plugin, and have a new shapefile with points on where I presume the center of each province is.

**What I'd ideally like is a list** (such as in the attribute table) next to each province (which are listen in the attribute table of the shapefile I'm working with) **with the coordinates for each centroid**. Is there any way to get this done? The only other thing I can imagine is writing down the coordinates of each centroid of each province manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add coordinates to your shapefile with the polygon centroids by "Vector > Geometry Tools > Export/Add Geometry Columns".

Then go to "layer properties > tab Join" to join that layer to your original province layer.  (Make sure you have a common field in both layers to join with.)  After the join, save your province layer as a new vector layer to establish the join.