# Why is field calculator returning NULL for $x and $y in line and polygon layers?

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, coordinates, xyz

I am trying to include XY coordinates in the attribute tables of several of my vector files; they are line and polygon files. I have tried two methods; first I used $x and $y in the field calculator (which I've used before and worked well).  When this returned NULL, I tried saving the file as a .CSV and using the methods described in this post:

[Get list of coordinates for points in a layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer)
(top answer describes using "GEOMETRY=AS_XY" in the 'save as' window).

Neither of these methods are working; they aren't returning errors, they just aren't returning values. I have tried re-importing my shapefiles, I have changed the CRS they occupy to try and force QGIS to recognize the location with no luck.

I'm using Windows 7, QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa.

Comment: QGIS version, OS and a sample file are needed to be provided here if you really want any help.

Comment: Right... sorry. Windows 7, 1.8.0 Lisboa.

Comment: Please share the problematic file. I've used these functions often and never encountered any such problem.

Comment: What kind of geometry do you have? $x and $y only works for point layers.

Comment: That would explain it.  The layers are mostly polygons.  I suppose an easy fix would be to make a points layer to represent the polygon layer and determine the coordinates from that.

Answer (score 2):

The $x and $y values only work for point layers.

Create a layer for polygon centroids and then that will give the x and y values using the $x and $y commands.