# Getting LonLat of a specific location in a specific projection on osm / google maps?

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, google-maps

How can I get the coordinates in, for example EPSG:4326 of a specific location, in either OpenStreetMaps or Google Maps?

Comment: maybe [this topic](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer) related to your problem

Answer (score 3):

As far as the projections are concerned, [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48952/64540) explains it really well. Once you have the coordinates in either `EPSG:4326` or `EPSG:3857` you should be able to covert them fairly easily, using either `PostgreSQL` or online convertors like [this](http://twcc.fr/en/#) one.

Getting the actual coordinates of a place or point in GoogleMaps is as simple as just clicking on the map. You should get a marker where you click along with a small pop-up which shows the name, coordinates of that point.
[image]