# Delete coordinates --> point still visible

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry

I used a 'batch geocode' to create coordinates. After that I exported excel --> csv --> shp. All went well. some coordinates are wrong though. after deleting them from the attribute table, the points are still visible on the canvas. even when I tried to select/delete the points from the canvas in QGIS.

I know it has something to do with updating geometry, but I can't find the right information online.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If you know the IDs of the wrong coordinates, try to delete them from Excel and repeat the process of exporting excel --> csv --> shp again and see if that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you export to shapefile using "Save As ...", the original CSV layer is still on the canvas. You have to remove it manually. Changing the CSV file content afterwards will not change the content of the already created shapefile.

Note that changing coordinates in the attribute table of the shapefile will not change the location of the point. You have to remove the whole line to delete the point. And if several points are on top of each other, you have to catch them all by selecting with a small rectangle.

Apart from that, zooming to extent (layer or project) will refresh the rendering of all features.

Comment: -remove wrong located coordinates manually in attribute table

Comment: -create a new csv file

Comment: -add the right coordinates

Comment: -for all coordinates i moved (by hand) i can update the coordinate, using this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcGIS, try the Repair Geometry tool.
It is in System Toolboxes > Data Management Tools.tbx > Features

> Inspects each feature in a feature class for geometry problems. Upon
>   discovery of a geometry problem, a relevant fix will be applied, and a
>   one-line description will be printed identifying the feature as well
>   as the problem encountered

It will delete the points if there is no geometry, there is also a Check Geometry tool if you don't want them to be deleted.