# How to export geometry as a table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sqlite, pipe-network, swmm

I am trying to use Qgis to produce the input file for SWMM and the first step is to produce the geometry tables. I need to export the geometry of elements as a tables with these format:

(poygons)

```
;;Subcatchment   X-Coord            Y-Coord           
;;-------------- ------------------ ------------------
Area1            134880.644         6495607.728       
Area1            135200.867         6495595.252       
Area1            134859.850         6495577.785       
Area1            134864.009         6495608.560       
Area2            135202.531         6495594.420       
Area2            135117.692         6495685.081       
Area2            134870.663         6495665.119       
Area2            134863.177         6495608.560
```

(lines)

```
;;Link           X-Coord            Y-Coord           
;;-------------- ------------------ ------------------
Link3            134941.633         6495830.023       
Link3            134953.814         6495860.476
```

(points)

```
;;Node           X-Coord            Y-Coord           
;;-------------- ------------------ ------------------
Node1            134866.732         6495657.169       
Node2            134918.668         6495651.752       
Node3            134919.624         6495674.375       
Node4            134933.644         6495678.517       
Node5            135002.538         6495870.626       
Outfall1         134890.879         6496098.005
```

So far, I have tried the MMQIS, but I do not know how to tailor the output:

```
"shapeid","x","y"
"0","134956.853261","6495850.73098"
"0","134951.891304","6495838.10054"
"0","134944.222826","6495660.82337"
"0","135027.44837","6495695.78261"
"0","135001.223092","6495794.37799"
"0","135013.690217","6495854.33967"
"0","135010.081522","6495867.4212"
"0","134956.853261","6495850.73098"
```

My guess is that a set of SQL sentences could do the work (I saw https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10113/36393), but I have no clue how to start them and what I need.

The elements are stored in separate files (GeoPackage or shape), I do not care about the attribute table (now) and I think I will be able to use a database.  I have PostGIS (I am very unexperienced on it), but maybe it is easier to work with a SpatiaLite file.

Comment: Your last table looks a lot like a csv, maybe exporting  your geometries as such works out.

Comment: @ErikLohmann it is a csv from MMQGIS, but formating it is very time consuming when you need to do it over and over

Comment: Meaning, you wish your exported csv to have values separated by tabstops and these lines?

Comment: Yes, using another key than "shapeid", getting rid of `""` and hopefully using fixed space delimited format (no tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s a bit puzzling to me why any software would require a fixed space delimited format as input...but anyway, AFAIK within QGIS your options are limited since both 'Save as...' -> CSV and the MMQGIS have their backdraws for your requirements.
PostgreSQL's `COPY` (or `/copy` if your DB rights are limited) does give you more flexibility in constructing the table structure, albeit still with no fixed space delimiter:

```
COPY (
    SELECT concat('Area', sub.id::text) AS "Subcatchment",
           ST_X(sub.geom) AS "X-Coord",
           ST_Y(sub.geom) AS "Y-Coord"
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
               (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom
        FROM <your_area_table>
    ) AS sub
) TO 'path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ' ' CSV HEADER;
```

This is the example query for your area table, for the lines just replace *'Subcatchment'* and *'Area'* with *'Link'* and refer to your line table (`<your_area_table>` in above query).
For your Points, use:

```
COPY (
    SELECT concat('Node', sub.id::text) AS "Node",
           ST_X(sub.geom) AS "X-Coord",
           ST_Y(sub.geom) AS "Y-Coord"
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
               geom
        FROM <your_point_table>
    ) AS sub
) TO 'path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ' ' CSV HEADER;
```

This gives you a CSV each, delimited by one space and without quotes (this is dependant on a few things, but should be true for your case). Note that your geometry column is called the kind-of standard *'geom'* in above queries, so name yours accordingly.

Comment: Fixed space delimited format due to an old coding that no one is going to change. The documentation of the input file is in the Appendix D of the User's Manual of SWMM https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPURL.cgi?Dockey=P100N3J6.txt is there is any interest

Comment: @Marco I don´t know, that still doesn´t explicitly say the input file has to be fixed space delimited. it does say that 'Data items can appear in any column of a line.' and mentions how a certain 'appearence' was created in the project file (which is an output file no?). it does also say that comment lines 'can' be prefixed with a semicolon. ...did you use this format before? in basically all language I know one reads out tabular data from file by it's (single) delimiter, and having to reduce arbitrary amounts of them to one is a little overhead...but that´s just me wondering about things ,)

Comment: @Marco **if** however this is absolutely necessary, consider using e.g. python to get full control over how the file is written. the *str.format()* function can easily implement fixed padding within lines (check out [this](https://pyformat.info/) blog for examples if you are not familiar). with the *psycopg2* module you can query a PostgreSQL/PostGIS DB with above examples (without the *COPY ... TO ...* of course) and write the returning rows to CSV using the *csv* module.

Comment: @ThingumaBod I have not tried other formats, but I will give them a try tomorrow, tabular or comma (semicolon is for comments) will make life a lot easier. Regarding the python `str.format()` sounds promising, it is me who is still a bad coder. I will have it in mind if I ever attempt to write a plugin for QGIS

Comment: Great! First time I execute an SQL sentence in QGIS. Just one more question. Is there a way to select the *inerior' of the line type data? i.e. only the vertex that are not the ends

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using SQL in PostGIS. You would get the points from your polygons/lines by "dumping" them from the source, then you print the X and Y components. The trick is to dump the points in a query and extract the X and Y in another, so you are 1) sure that X and Y match and 2) you don't have to dump the points twice.
Using fake data, it would be:

```
with src as 
   (select 1 as id, 
    st_geomfromtext('polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))') as geom
   UNION 
    select 2 as id, 
    st_geomfromtext('polygon((10 10, 20 10, 20 20, 10 20, 10 10))') as geom),
dumppts as 
  (select id, 
  (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom from src)
select id, 
       st_x(geom), st_y(geom) from dumppts;

 id | st_x | st_y
----+------+------
  1 |    1 |    1
  1 |    2 |    1
  1 |    2 |    2
  1 |    1 |    2
  1 |    1 |    1
  2 |   10 |   10
  2 |   20 |   10
  2 |   20 |   20
  2 |   10 |   20
  2 |   10 |   10
(10 rows)
```

Using real data it would be similar to

```
 with dumppts as 
      (select Subcatchment, 
      (st_dumppoints(geom)).geom from myAreaLayer)
 select Subcatchment, 
        st_x(geom) as "X-Coord", 
        st_y(geom) as "Y-Coord" from dumppts;
```

Comment: Sorry for such silly questions, but in your example, is `myAreaLayer` the geometry already in a PostGIS database? Which needs an attribute called `Subcatchment`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the geometries are in Postgres. You can change the `Subcatchment` for whatever field uniquely identify your features