# Selecting the interior of line type data in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, export, swmm

I have asked about exporting geometry as a table ([Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268888/how-to-export-geometry-as-a-table-in-qgis)) and I got a very nice answer about how to do it with an SQL instruction.

Is there a way to select only the *inerior* of line type data? i.e. only the vertex that are not the ends.
[image]

The following instruction will produce all vertex

```
SELECT sub.name AS "Pipe",
               ST_X(sub.geom) AS "X-Coord",
               ST_Y(sub.geom) AS "Y-Coord"
        FROM (
            SELECT name,
                   (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom
            FROM conduits
        ) AS sub
```

Here is the output:

```
'1570','4978.95','2421.05'
'1570','2494.74','2421.05'
'1600','2494.74','2421.05'
'1600','2494.74','7536.84'
'1602','4957.89','7536.84'
'1602','2494.74','7536.84'
'8040','8115.79','3450.84'
'8040','9107.73','4350.80'
'8040','7463.16','7536.84'
```

I would like to get only:

```
'8040','9107.73','4350.80'
```

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever, topologically speaking. The gap between interior and boundary is *infinitely* small. It is the boundary which defines the interior, so they cannot be separated. An infinite number of features could be created between the gap between the first and second vertices, and a like number between N-1 and N.

Comment: I think I did it! @Vince you are right if we were talking about real numbers (R^2), but we are somewhere else. I had to diggest the *Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)* slowly to write down an SQL command. I took the hints and the picture from here: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/de9im.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)

So far, it works for the example.

```
SELECT subpoints.name AS "Pipe",
    ST_X(subpoints.geom) AS "X-Coord",
    ST_Y(subpoints.geom) AS "Y-Coord"
FROM (SELECT name,
             (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom
      FROM conduits
      )  AS subpoints,
      (SELECT name,
              geom AS geom
      FROM conduits
      )  AS sublines
WHERE subpoints.name=sublines.name
AND  ST_Relate(subpoints.geom, sublines.geom, '0FF******')
```