# Converting multicolumns CSV to Raster Format

Tags: raster, csv, multi-polygon

I need to convert multicolumn CSV file in a raster.
I read some similar question, but my problem is that I have different columns in addition to "longitude" and "latitude" (I would like to manage a 20 years data). I don't want and cannot separate the columns into other files, are too many. Values are average temperature per year. Header Columns are:

*lat*, *lon*, *year(1)*, *year(2)*, *year(3)*... *year(n)*.

Should I first somehow order my CSV and the translate it in a multiband raster?

Comment: You need to create 20 rasters then, because each pixel can only have one value. Or one raster with 20 bands. Btw, which software do you use to do this? In QGIS you can choose which column shall be used as rastervalue.

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/getting-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-layer-using-qgis if you create a virtual point layer you can rasterize by triangulation or IDW, whichever supports your analysis, for each field though if you've got a heap of them it might be time to try a bit of python.

Comment: I use Grass! But to create raster I can use even QGIS, then I need to work with the raster on Grass. Thank you MrXsquared

Comment: In any case, I was thinking to use R to create raster... I was abel to create one raster, but multiband raster seems a step further. Thank you for your help