# Last edited information missing when used QGIS - Dxf to Shp

Tags: qgis, convert, autocad, shapefile, dxf

I am doing as constructed drawings which require the information to be in a GIS system and more specifically drainage as constructed drawings.

I must have a separate file for Pipes and Pits. First I use Autocad, save as a DXF then use Quantum GIS to convert the DXF to SHP. So the problem is that the last edited piece of information from the autocad file is missing when i convert it. I can go back and change the last edited line, polygon or polyline and the last thing touched will still be missing. Help?

I have looked on the QGIS website but haven't been able to find anything helpful.

Comment: Please clarify: When does the feature vanish? On a)  opening the DXF in QGIS or b) saving the layer to SHP.

Comment: How are you doing your dxf export from Autocad? Saveas? Are you adding a new item at end or moving and item. does it disappear or doesn't show the edit (change)? I guess you don't have Autocad Map 3d. It will export shape file directly. I can't think of a good reason for the dissapearance, If the last edit is not changed then I would suggest doing a save (dwg), close re-open and then saveas.

Comment: Hi All, any updates on this, I am experiencing the same, and want to give the originator of the dxf file some explicit instructions as to how to save the file so as I get it all. ta

Comment: Just to create a neat loop of 'logic', see my answer just now when we are concerned with going from Shp to Dxf  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-gis-support-dxf-and-or-dwg

Answer (score 2):

To lighten some happy mood, I suggest you to use **FME Server**. Since FME is a very powerful engine, your conversion should be done without much complexion. Figuratively, numerous format can be selected here. But bear in mind that the files should be organized. Otherwise, it would means nothing.

**Click here**: http://fmeserver.com/userweb/sharper/Portal/EasyTranslator/index.html

The conversion process should works.